# HashMap is null so i cant get my data shown in the emulator from Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

`Android studio` showed a warning so with `ALT + ENTER` the code

```
 val name = data[USERNAME] as String
```

became

```
val name = data?.get(USERNAME) as String
```

but my emulator is still crashing

```
 thoughtsCollectionRef.get()
.addOnSuccessListener { snapshot -> 
for(document in snapshot.documents){
val data = document.data 

//this is my code after listening to android studio 

val name = data?.get(USERNAME) as String
val timestamp = data?.get(TIMESTAMP) as Date
val thoughtTxt = data?.get(THOUGHT_TXT) as String
val numLikes = data?.get(NUM_LIKES) as Long
val numComments = data?.get(NUM_COMMENTS) as Long
 val documentId = document.id
```

//I edited every other variable with the `safecall ?.get()` and its still crashing

```
 val newThought = Thought(name,timestamp,thoughtTxt,numLikes.toInt(),numComments.toInt(),
                    documentId)


thoughts.add(newThought)
}

 thoughtsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Comment: What's the error/exception in LogCat ?

Comment: Please post your database screenshot and poko for better understanding.

Comment: 08-21 09:49:28.578 4088-4088/com.example.rndm E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.rndm, PID: 4088
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.firebase.Timestamp cannot be cast to java.util.Date
        at com.example.rndm.MainActivity$onCreate$2.onSuccess(MainActivity.kt:44)
        at com.example.rndm.MainActivity$onCreate$2.onSuccess(MainActivity.kt:16)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: `val timestamp = data?.get(TIMESTAMP) as Date` This field is not a Date but a Timestamp

Comment: @TodorGeorgiev Please check updated answer it will help you in better way

Comment: im following a course from Alison  that uses Firebase. i have continued the class before but this error kept bugging me. It says that the Date cannot be cast but i have done exactly as the tutorial said

Comment: 08-21 09:59:36.822 4199-4199/com.example.rndm E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.rndm, PID: 4199
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.firebase.Timestamp cannot be cast to java.sql.Timestamp
        at com.example.rndm.MainActivity$onCreate$2.onSuccess(MainActivity.kt:45)
        at com.example.rndm.MainActivity$onCreate$2.onSuccess(MainActivity.kt:17)

Answer (score 1):

The `data?.get(TIMESTAMP)` call returns a [Firebase `Timestamp`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp) object. So instead of casting it to `Date`, you should cast it to `com.google.firebase.Timestamp`:

```
// imports
import com.google.firebase.Timestamp

...

// rest of the code
val timestamp = data?.get(TIMESTAMP) as? Timestamp
```

If you want to end up with a `Date` object, you can use the `Timestamp` method `toDate()`:

```
val date = timestamp?.toDate()
```

Also note that you should use a safe casting operator `as?` instead of `as` in this case:

```
val name = data?.get(USERNAME) as? String
val timestamp = data?.get(TIMESTAMP) as? Timestamp
val thoughtTxt = data?.get(THOUGHT_TXT) as? String
val numLikes = data?.get(NUM_LIKES) as? Long
val numComments = data?.get(NUM_COMMENTS) as? Long
```

The `data?.get(KEY)` may produce a `null` object, which can't be cast to any type and the operation will result in a crash.

Comment: the similar way i tried and it says Unresolved Reference `USERNAME`

Comment: @Ashish I'm assuming the constants `USERNAME`, `TIMESTAMP`, etc. are already defined. The OP mentioned he has these variables defined.